# Cannot establish relationship between two tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to create a relation between lising and attribute table in laravel for that i have used following code to establish relationship between them but the data in my view is not coming from both the tables. I'm getting following error:

> Call to undefined relationship [adListAttributes] on model
>   [App\Models\AdListing].
>
> Here listing can have as many attribute associated with and attributes
>   can be associated to many listings

```
ad_listings:
id 
    title
    name 
    date
```

```
ad_list_attributes table :

    id
    listing_id
    name
```

```php
    namespace App\Models;
    use Eloquent;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class AdListAttribute extends Model
    {
        protected $table = "ad_list_attributes";


        public function Listings()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('AdListing', 'id', 'listing_id');
        } 
    }
```

```php
    namespace App\Models;
    use Eloquent;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class AdListing extends Model
    {
       protected $table = "ad_listings";

       public function Attributes()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('AdListAttribute', 'listing_id', 'id');
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are using `belongsToMany` in both the models.This will cause a problem.

In `AdListAttribute` model,

```
    public function listing_information()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\AdListing', 'id', 'listing_id');
    }
```

In `AdListing` model,

```
   public function adlisting_attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AdListAttribute', 'listing_id', 'id');
    }
```

You can get the results using,

```
 $response = AdListing::get();
 if($response->adlisting_attributes)
 {
   foreach($response->adlisting_attributes as $attribute)
   {
       echo $attribute->name;
   }
 }
```

Comment: It is giving me Property [adlisting_attributes] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: You changed the relationship name or not ? change it as i did.it will work.

Comment: Provide `App\modelname` instead of `modelname` in relationship

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that ur not calling the relationship with the right name i assume

```
$listings = AdListing::with('Attributes')->get();
```

**Update :**

Try this :

```
use App\Models\AdListAttribute;
//
return $this->belongsToMany(AdListAttribute::class, 'listing_id', 'id');
```

Same for other model, then try

Comment: It is not working, Class 'AdListAttribute' not found

Comment: @user3653474 but as u noticied that the exception is different, now it found the relationship method in the class, but couldn't find the relation class by name!